# Use angular translation as parameter of a notification function

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I would like to be able to pass a string message as parameter to my function.
The matToolTip is working without problem, but i don't arrive to pass it to my function AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral :

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" matTooltip="{{ 'GROUPS.addUserToGroup' | translate }}" matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral('add', 'I WANT MY VARIABLE GROUPS.addUserToGroup THERE ?');">Ajouter <mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon></button>
```

Angular 11
Typescript 4.0.5
Thanks for help !

Comment: Just pass your parameter without `' '` like this (click)="AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral('add', GROUPS.addUserToGroup);"

Comment: No it doesn't work at all :( https://prnt.sc/wf69sf

Comment: could you post your component.ts

Comment: My post is not att all related to my component.ts
It's just a problem of syntax to translate in a function

As you see "matToolTip" is working, i need the same thing but as a parameter of function :)

Comment: I think there are some misunderstanding you are passing an argument to this function `AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral` which doesn't accept the second parameter, while `GROUPS.addUserToGroup` is working in translation Pipe so there is no problem with him, and the problem related to `(click) function`

Comment: If you want to pass the 'GROUPS.addUserToGroup' as string it should work and your html notations is fine, but If you want to pass the result of translation pipe to your AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral  function then it will be another issue

Comment: I would like to pass the translation pipe to my AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral 
(In order to display the message in the language selected by user)

Comment: Are you using a custom translate pipe or a specific core theme?

Comment: I'm using ngx-translate, so no specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate message in your typescript and you are using `ngx-translate` just import TranslateService in your component and declare it in the constructor

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

and update your constructor to add `public translate: TranslateService`

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {}
```

Now you can use this `this.translate.get('myKey');` wherever you want, in your case

```
AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral(arg1,key){
  ...
  let message = this.translate.get(key);
  console.log(message)
  ...
}
```

Now just pass the key from your HTML template

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" matTooltip="{{ 'GROUPS.addUserToGroup' | translate }}" matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="AddRemoveUserOfGroupGeneral('add', 'GROUPS.addUserToGroup');">Ajouter <mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i was doing that since few hours in the app ;)